# Why is the geomagnetic north pole at a different location from the magnetic north pole?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, geophysics, dipole

According to this site
[Magnetic North, Geomagnetic and Magnetic Poles](http://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/poles/polesexp.html)

*The Geomagnetic poles (dipole poles) are the intersections of the Earth's surface and the axis of a bar magnet hypothetically placed at the center the Earth by which we approximate the geomagnetic field. There is such a pole in each hemisphere, and the poles are called as "the geomagnetic north pole" and "the geomagnetic south pole", respectively. On the other hand, the magnetic poles are the points at which magnetic needles become vertical. There also are "the magnetic north pole" and "the magnetic south pole".*

[image]

But why does the compass needle not point to the geomagnetic pole?  I mean why aren't they both at the same location?

Answer (score 6):

Earth's magnetic field *isn't* really a [dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole), but a [dynamic field due to the convection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory) occurring in the planet's core (consists of molten iron). The model below shows a simulation of the magnetic field (blue is pointing towards the core while yellow points away), the cluster of curves in the middle is the planet's core.

[image]

The geomagnetic pole is the location of the pole **if** earth's magnetic field were a *simple* dipole (no convection-driven fields).

Note also that, in your image, the geomagnetic pole hasn't moved much in the last century while the magnetic pole has. This is because every several thousand years, the [magnetic poles flip sides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_reversals) (a non-constant rate of reversal, so we can't really say a definitive time-frame).

Comment: are they usually in close proximity to each other?

Comment: Sometimes. During a reversal, they're not usually anywhere near each other (the pole was once in Oregon (but long before) it was Oregon).

Comment: Which one are geomagnetic phenomena centered around, like for example aurora?

Comment: I believe that the aurorae are located near the geomagnetic pole, but I'm not entirely certain of that.

Comment: Another way to say this is that the geomagnetic poles are by definition required to be antipodal (it's the best fit to a dipolar field.) The observed magnetic poles are not so required.

Comment: Might the downvoter care to mention what they think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Why has the geomagnetic pole moved? Is this because the earths angle changes?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof no, it's mostly due to the fact that it's a convective system (i.e., moving fluid). It can also be included by currents flowing in the ionosphere, the radiation belts and the Earth's magnetosphere.