# As the World Turns

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, geophysics

Does the Earth's axis change with the magnetic reversal as it is taking place?

[image]

Comment: climatic/astronomic and magnetic poles are different

Comment: the answers are here : [Does the geomagnetic field rotate?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127766/does-the-geomagnetic-field-rotate)